# How can I write text to an external file using JQuery/JavaScript/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I have some text stored in a POST variable that I need to append to an HTML file. I want to do within my PHP webpage, but it could use HTML, JQuery, Javascript, or anything else that will run natively. I've tried the PHP approach, but it hasn't worked despite my numerous attempts. Always a 500 internal server error. And I can't find anything on writing to files using JQuery, so if anyone out there knows something I don't, it would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: *"append to an HTML file"* - As in, make a permanent change to an html file that is on your (PHP) web server? (So all future requests for that page will get the updated version?) I hope you're validating your input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing directly to you html/php documents is extremely bad practice. As your comment said you need to validate the input and if you make a mistake you could screw up your whole website.

There are a couple of options you could use:

- localstorage: This saves the changes to the browser of the user. This means that the changes wont be on the server. Very easy solution.
- Add a database: With PHP it is very easy to add a SQL databse. Write some functions that write the data to the database and read the data from there. Safer than writing directly to HTML/PHP but still needs validation
- Do some extreme reading into all the PHP IO functions. You need some extreme good handling if you want this site live.

I think that with the DB you`ll manage, just be safe and build in some security

Comment: You could also use http://parse.com . Thier javascript  API makes it quite simple to store and retrieve data like this

Comment: @DelightedD0D Didnt know it, thanks :) I dont know what OP wants, but if he wants some simple content management then a DB on his own server will do.

Comment: for sure, just wanted to add parse to the list, if you already know javascript but not php, you can be up and running with parse in 10-15 mins while the learning curve to safely use  SQL and PHP is a good deal more involved :)

Comment: @jimmyjansen Added a fourth option: Laravel (a PHP framework). Since the OP mentioned PHP, I figured it might be best to suggest something that works more or less "right out of the box."